# What to do with the following webservice response?

Tags: iphone, web-services, ios, soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<DownloadFaxDocResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<DownloadFaxDocResult>
<FileDownload xmlns="" />
</DownloadFaxDocResult>
</DownloadFaxDocResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The documentation says that I am to get a base64 encoded TIF/PNG file. I don't see anything. Does this mean something wrong with my web service call?

The documentation is at:

http://glostream.faxregistration.com/sfaxapi.asmx?op=DownloadFaxDoc

And this is my header code:

```
//---set the headers---
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [xmlString length]];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/DownloadFaxDoc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    //---set the HTTP method and body---
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: data];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd say there's something wrong with the query.  If you were getting base64 encoded data, it would look something like this:

```
<DownloadFaxDocResult>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA25CSFPinfIIQQvaGIMQyjrYj98hohhOgNRYxhGH1F7AghhOg
 NOviD1GCCF6QxFjGER ... LOTS MORE ... <DownloadFaxDocResult>
```

Comment: Found out that the web service documentation had a tag misspelling. Imagine that.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you attached, it shows:

```
<soap:Body>
   <DownloadFaxDocResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <DownloadFaxDocResult>xml</DownloadFaxDocResult>
   </DownloadFaxDocResponse>    
</soap:Body>
```

The return result is expected as XMLNode object, not a binary file.